# Websocket .close() is not recognised

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ws

Im trying to close a websocket from an npm package that connects to a third party service.

I instantiate the ws by doing:

```
ws = BitMexPlus({
            apiKeyID:     rows[i].bot_key.apiKeyID,
            apiKeySecret: rows[i].bot_key.apiKeySecret
})
```

This then calls another np package within it and makes the connection to the 3rd party.

How ever I want to be able to close the ws at will so naturally I do:

```
ws.close()
```

but I get the error:

```
ws.close is not a function
```

how ever for error handling and proper logging I do:

```
ws.on('end', async (code) => {console.log(code)})
```

and this works flawlessly.

Keep in mind the code dealing with this error handling is buried all the way inside the second package. So technically I should be able to close it with the ws instantiation.

How should I be calling the endpoint to close it?

Comment: Definitely not an expert but ```process.exit(0)``` might be the move. It's, at least, what the Bitmex Plus npm documentation seems to suggest.

Comment: process.exit(0) literally kills the entire container